# How to use CLOB datatype for storing limitless characters in column each rows?

Tags: oracle, datatypes, sqlplus, clob

I want to use CLOB datatype instead of varchar2(4000) and long, in which I want store limitless characters . However, its easy to declare the string based column to CLOB but the main problem is when I insert the paragraph it stores and on runtime when check it shows just a single line.. As am new, your guidance will help me a-lot thanks.

I have tried this, on runtime it only displays limited characters. I want to store one page paragraph in single row and on runtime it displays all the characters of the paragraph.

Note:

Using SQL*PLUS
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a display limitation. By default SQL*Plus shows a limited amount of characters for LONG and LOB columns. This limit can be increased as:

```
set long 2000000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, it works fine.